# Commited my git repo but i cant see repo on website

Tags: git, github

I am learning Git and I did what the tutorial (like [this one](http://shaun.boyblack.co.za/blog/2009/03/14/getting-started-with-git-on-mac-os-x/)) said in all way, but could not figure it out what is the problem.
Here are the steps I followed:

- First initialize the repo:

  ```
  MyThReYas-MacBook-Pro:~ MyThReYa$ mkdir serraproj
  MyThReYas-MacBook-Pro:~ MyThReYa$ cd serraproj
  MyThReYas-MacBook-Pro:serraproj MyThReYa$ git init
  Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/MyThReYa/serraproj/.git/
  MyThReYas-MacBook-Pro:serraproj MyThReYa$ ls
  MyThReYas-MacBook-Pro:serraproj MyThReYa$ ls -a
  .   ..  .git
  ```
- Then add a file and commit a file:

  ```
  MyThReYas-MacBook-Pro:serraproj MyThReYa$ ls
  index.html
  MyThReYas-MacBook-Pro:serraproj MyThReYa$ git add index.html
  MyThReYas-MacBook-Pro:serraproj MyThReYa$ git status
  # On branch master
  #
  # Initial commit
  #
  # Changes to be committed:
  #   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
  #
  #   new file:   index.html
  #
  MyThReYas-MacBook-Pro:serraproj MyThReYa$ git commit -m"this is a try"
  [master (root-commit) 4acb983] this is a try
  1 file changed, 87 insertions(+)
  create mode 100644 index.html
  MyThReYas-MacBook-Pro:serraproj MyThReYa$ git status
  # On branch master
  nothing to commit, working directory clean
  MyThReYas-MacBook-Pro:serraproj MyThReYa$ git status
  ```

Yet, I don't see that file on my website on the remote server.
What did I miss?

Comment: For instance: a good way to improve your question would be at least to mention the link to the tutorial you followed.

Comment: Another good way to improve it, would be to say what exactly went wrong and what you expected instead.

Comment: Moderators have diamonds. You know this @vonc Five peer users have found the question lacking, hence the closing. And seeing three re-open votes, but not a single edit to improve the question shows a lack on that side to improve matters over blaming others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any [`git push`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).

If you don't push to the remote server where your website is, you cannot see what you have committed locally.
That would be something like:

```
cd ~/serraproj
git remote add origin /url/to/your/server/repo.git
git push -u origin master
```